# How to fix "Subquery returns multiple values"?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i'm trying to write a stored procedure who have to verify if name Dont exist in my database and if name does not exist i create a new line with name and pass.

i have this error : Subquery returns multiple values.

```
    this is my code :

    if((select Nom from prorio where Nom = @p_nom) = '')

    insert into Prorio (Nom, mdp) VALUES (@p_nom, @p_mdp);
    else if((select Nom from prorio where Nom = @p_nom)!='')
    return 2;
```

Comment: I might suggest that you have a *data* problem if the subquery returns multiple values.

Comment: Why would someone's(?) name be blank in the first place? Also, this clearly isn't a Scalar function, so why are you using `RETURN` to return something that isn't an error code? If you need to return a scalar function from an SP, use an `OUTPUT` parameter.

Comment: it would be blank because before the user register, the name dont exist and select is supposed to return empty string ? and i tought used return because its look easiest to use it in a webservice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the logic you are after is:

```
IF (@p_nom = '' AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Prorio WHERE Nom = '')) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO dbo.Prorio (Nom,mdp)
    VALUES(@p_nom,@p_mdp);

END
ELSE IF @p_nom != '' BEGIN 

    SET @OutputParam = 2;
END;
```

You'll need to add `@OutputParam` to your SP's definition (as an `OUTPUT` Parameter) and probably give it a "better" name.

This does seem like an `XY` problem though. The logic you have means that if the person has a blank (`''`) name, they can *only* be inserted if *other* rows in the table already have a blank (`''`) name. That *seems* like a design flaw.